# custom authorizer causing CORS errors

Tags: python, reactjs, amazon-web-services

I am having a small anoying issue in AWS API gateway,

I am using a custom authorizer to validate my POST and even get API calls

I have enabled CORS on the resource successfully and I am able to invoke the APIs successfully

Now heres the issue, When I add the custom authorizer to the method in the resource in API gateway, I start getting the  "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' errors in my browser from my react front end app

Please What am I doing wrong? and how do I resolve this issue

Thanks

See the code of my custom authorizer below

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    """ extract token from header """

    entered_request_token = event['headers']['Authorization']
    entered_request_token2 = event['multiValueHeaders']['Authorization']
    if entered_request_token == "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX":
        response = {
            "isAuthorized": True,
            "context": {
                "anyOtherParam": "Value"
            }
        }
    else:
        response = {
            "isAuthorized": False,
            "context": {
                "anyOtherParam": "Value"
            }
        }

    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure CORS in API Gateway or as part of your response? We use CORS on our side, but we're passing the CORS values back in the response - we have not configured it in API Gateway.

Comment: we configured  CORS in API Gateway